# Multiple docker servers using same containers

Tags: docker

I have multiple VMs that are all running Docker, and I need them to be all able to start/stop the same container. For example, if I had a text document in one container on one VM, I would need to be able to start and edit that text document on any of the Docker servers (so they are all interconnected). I was thinking I could put the containers on a shared instance, but then I wasn't sure how to be able to get each Docker server to launch them from there. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you'll need to be a bit more specific as to what you are trying to achieve here. Are you trying to share the same data between containers?

Comment: Yep. I was testing this with Minecraft servers, but I could do with using it for other things too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to share data between Docker containers I'd start with either a data volume or a data volume container:

> **Data volumes**
>
> A data volume is a specially-designated directory within one or more
>   containers that bypasses the Union File System to provide several
>   useful features for persistent or shared data:
>
> - Volumes are initialized when a container is created
> - Data volumes can be shared and reused between containers
> - Changes to a data volume are made directly
> - Changes to a data volume will not be included when you update an    image
> - Volumes persist until no containers use them
>
> **Creating and mounting a Data Volume Container**
>
> If you have some persistent data that you want to share between
>   containers, or want to use from non-persistent containers, it's best
>   to create a named Data Volume Container, and then to mount the data
>   from it.

https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

You specify a data volume with the `-v` option to the `docker run` command. You can then use the `--volumes-from` to mount volumes from a docker volume container to any other containers you want to share the data with. Full details with examples at the above link.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Managed to miss this when making the Google rounds!